# Music plays when running program in Eclipse, but not when running Jar executable

Tags: java

When I run my program in Eclipse, the music runs just fine when I access the part of the program that runs it. When I compile it as a jar, however, the music does not play, and everything else works fine.

I am making a 2d side scroller game, and have a class for each level. In the class for the first level, I have this code in the constructor:

```
LoadClip();
```

and this method later on in the class:

```
private void LoadClip() {
    Clip c = null;
        try {
            AudioInputStream music = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("wily.wav"));
            c = AudioSystem.getClip();
            c.open(music);
            c.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the compiled jar actually contains the music file. Remember jarfiles are essentially zips, you can just open them with something like winrar.

Comment: Are you getting any exception trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot read a resource as a stream from a jar

to solve: 
replace `getResourceAsStream` with `getResource`

like so:

`AudioInputStream music = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("wily.wav"));`

Hope this helps!

Comment: No need, happy to help out